# Recommendation for Open source alternative to SteerMouse

Tags: open-source, osx, mouse

I am looking for an open source alternative to the program steer mouse:

[SteerMouse](http://plentycom.jp/en/steermouse/index.html)

The software would need to be for mac. I am currently aware of SensibleSideButtons program and this does not fit my needs. I am not looking for all of the features to steer mouse. I have a first generation Bluetooth apple mouse (this is not the magic mouse). The apple mouse only has 1 button and movement and that is all.

I would like the software to atleast have the functionality of me pressing a set of buttons in order to scroll with the mouse. And to have customizable options for the scroll speed and bindings for the double click and single click.

Thank you.

Edit:

SteerMouse is a utility that lets you freely customize buttons, wheels and cursor speed. Both USB and Bluetooth mice are supported, no matter whether the mouse is designed for Windows or Mac.

You can assign a function to combinations of a button and modifier keys ( command shift option control ). In addition to it, you can assign a function to combinations of buttons.

Comment: Please explain what SteerMouse is and then list all of the features that you __need__, and then would like, rather than expect people to go off an look at an external site and try to read your mind.